# Flash does not work after server change

Tags: xml, flash, security

I am getting the message "Unable to load xml" after a server change. Could this be a crossdomain.xml issue?

The following error message is more detail.

> Server Error in Application
>
> Internet Information Services 7.5 Error Summary HTTP Error 404.8 - Not
>   Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the
>   URL that contains a hiddenSegment section. Detailed Error Information
>   ModuleRequestFilteringModule NotificationBeginRequest
>   HandlerStaticFile Error Code0x00000000 Requested
>   URLhttp://www.travelpro.com:80/controlpanel/bin/assets/main_navigation.xml
>   Physical
>   PathD:\home\travelpro.com\wwwroot\controlpanel\bin\assets\main_navigation.xml
>   Logon MethodNot yet determined Logon UserNot yet determined Most
>   likely causes:
>
> ```
> Request filtering is configured for the Web server and it contains a hiddenSegments section that allows the server administrator to deny
> ```
>
> access to specific directories.
>
> Things you can try:
>
> ```
> Verify configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/hiddenSegments
> ```
>
> settings in the applicationhost.config or the web.config file.
>
> Links and More Information This is a security feature. Do not change
>   this feature unless the scope of the change is fully understood. If
>   content should be served from a specific directory being denied by
>   this setting, remove the denied directory from
>   configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/hiddenSegments.

Here is my crossdomain.xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Sounds like an iisue with your IIS server, rather than a cross domain issue.  Strange error message, but if you Google it you should [find more info](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments)

Comment: Thank you, Sunil, I think you are correct. This was a flash module that worked perfectly until the server was changed. I am not the system administrator, so I can't get into the IIS server configuration. But I will tell them to look there. Thanks again.